# Using sharedPreferences for a login screen not comparing

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I am having trouble getting my Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY to compare with a EditText box. In a activity i have the user enter a password to be saved as the Password_pref and another activity for them to log into but i keep getting "Incorrect Password" even tho the password_pref is set as "testing" and the editText set the same. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
package com.jandj.production;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class LogIn extends Activity {

private EditText pass1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.password);
    pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);

    SharedPreferences passwdfile = getSharedPreferences(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY,MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String p3 = passwdfile.getString(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, null);
    final String p1 = pass1.getText().toString(); 
    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login); 
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            if (p3.equals(p1)) {     
                startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this,Main.class));  
                 } 
            else {     
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            });
    };
    }
```

Comment: yes you will get the "Incorrect Password" always.. as you r setting the default to Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY to null and then straight away comparing it with the text of the edit text... Have you stored the data in Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY in the previous screen and commited it..

Comment: so what is it that i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not stored the password entered by the user in the sharedpreference and commited.. for sample the code is

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, "My password");

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
```

once it is done.. you can get it using passwdfile.getString(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, null); and then check...

Comment: in my other activity called Password i use the code u linked.

Comment: if (p1.equals(p2)) {
       if (p1.length() >=6 || p2.length() >=6) {
        Editor passwdfile = getSharedPreferences(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, 0).edit();
        String md5hash = getMd5Hash(p1);
        passwdfile.putString(Password.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY,md5hash);
        passwdfile.commit();
        messages.setText("Password updated!");
       }
       else

Comment: what does p1 and p2 contains... and i am not able to see your else part... is this is the code that you used in the first activity...

Answer (score 0):

When your application first time loads you can ask user for password and store it in preferences like above as per Dinash's answer with sharedPreferences and SharedPreferences.Editor.

Then when you want to retrieve that password for comparison, make sharedpreference passwdfile and use that passwdfile.getString() as you used in your code.

:)